# How to define inclusions in FEM/NDSolve?

Tags: differential-equations, mesh, finite-element-method, simulation

I am trying to simulate the compaction process of hot mix asphalts and want to do this with mathematica's FEM libraries. How can I define inclusions in meshes (i.e aggregate particles in the binder) while using the FEM and NDSolve capabilities of Mathematica? I am new to FEM analysis so my question may be a bit rudimentary.

Comment: Have a look at the documentation of [ToElementMesh](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/ToElementMesh.html) and/or the [mesh generation tutorial](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/ElementMeshCreation.html). If you do not find anything there then you might need to clarify you question a bit.